# Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

Tags: header, php, cookie

Данная проблема возникает при авторизации (работают сессии).

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at Z:\home\bbb\www\aaa.php:59) in Z:\home\bbb\www\module.php on line 100
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at Z:\home\bbb\www\aaa.php:59) in Z:\home\bbb\www\module.php on line 101

Авторизация проходит. Но перед выводом - Привет, user - пишутся данные сообщения.
Читал, что возможно это связано с проблеами до <?php и после ?>. Но вроде как никаких пробелов в коде не присутствует. Кроме того - это может быть связано с кодировкой. Все файлы должны быть сохранены в UTF 8 без Bom. Все так и сделано. Но все равно появляются данные сообщения.
Прошу помочь)
Вот код странички, на которой выводится - Привет, user.

```
<?php
include_once 'conf.php';

$auth = new auth(); //~ Создаем новый объект класса

//~ Авторизация
if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
    if (!$auth->authorization()) {
        $error = $_SESSION['error'];
        unset ($_SESSION['error']);
    }
}

//~ выход
if (isset($_GET['exit'])) $auth->exit_user();

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="login_panel/js/pngfix/supersleight-min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<!-- Panel -->
<div id="toppanel">
    <div id="panel">
        <div class="content clearfix">
    <?php
            if(!$_SESSION['id_user']):
    ?>

            <div class="left">
                <!-- Login Form -->

                    <h1>Войти на сайт</h1>
    <?php
                    $k='';

                    $auth = new auth(); //~ Создаем новый объект класса

            $k.='
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <label class="grey" for="login">Логин:</label>
                    <input class="field" type="text" name="login" value="'.@$_POST['login'].'" size="23" />
                    <label class="grey" for="passwd">Пароль:</label>
                    <input class="field" type="password" name="passwd" id="" size="23" />
                    <input type="submit" value="send" name="send" />
                </form>
            ';
            print $k;
    ?>
            </div>
            <div class="left right">            
                <!-- Register Form -->
                    <h1>Регистрация</h1>                  
    <?php
                    $reg = new auth(); //~ Создаем новый объект класса

                    $form = '

                    <form action="" method="post">
                    <label class="grey" for="login">Логин:</label>
                    <input class="field" type="text" name="login" id="" value="'.@$_POST['login'].'" size="23" />
                    <label class="grey" for="passwd">Пароль:</label>
                    <input class="field" type="password" name="passwd" id="" size="23" />
                    <label class="grey" for="passwd2">Повторите Пароль:</label>
                    <input class="field" type="password" name="passwd2" id="" size="23" />
                    <label class="grey" for="mail">E-mail:</label>
                    <input class="field" type="text" name="mail" value="'.@$_POST['mail'].'" size="23" />
                    <input type="submit" value="send" name="send" />
                    </form>';
        if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
        if ($reg->reg($_POST['login'], $_POST['passwd'], $_POST['passwd2'], $_POST['mail'])) {
        print '
            <h2>Регистрация успешна.</h2>
            Вы можете войти. 
        ';
        } else print $form;
        } else print $form;
    ?>
            </div>
    <?php   
            else:   
    ?>
            <div class="left">

            <h1>Вы вошли на сайт</h1>
            <a href="?exit">Выйти</a>

            </div>

            <div class="left right">
            </div>
    <?php   
            endif;  
    ?>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- /login -->

    <!-- The tab on top --> 
    <div class="tab">
        <ul class="login">
            <li class="left">&nbsp;</li>
            <li><?php if ($auth->check()) $r.='Привет, '.$_SESSION['login_user'].'';
            else {
    $r.='Привет, Гость';}
print $r;?>!</li>
            <li id="toggle">
                <a id="open" class="open" href="#"><?php echo $_SESSION['id_user']?'Открыть панель':'Войти на сайт';?></a>
                <a id="close" style="display: none;" class="close" href="#">Закрыть панель</a>          
            </li>
            <li class="right">&nbsp;</li>
        </ul> 
    </div> <!-- / top -->

</div> <!--panel -->
```

Сам файл conf.php:

```
<?php
//~ Старт сессии, файл должен быть сохранен без DOM информации
session_start();

include_once 'module.php';

//~ Параметры потключения к бд
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_login = 'root';
$db_passwd = '';
$db_name = 'login';

// подключаемся к бд
$db = new mysql(); //~ Создаем новый объект класса
$db -> connect($db_host, $db_login, $db_passwd, $db_name);
?>
```

И тот самый module.php:

```
function check() {
    if (isset($_SESSION['id_user']) and isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) return true;
    else {
        //~ проверяем наличие кук
        if (isset($_COOKIE['id_user']) and isset($_COOKIE['code_user'])) {
            //~ куки есть - сверяем с таблицей сессий
            $db = new mysql(); //~ создаем новый объект класса
            $id_user=$db->screening($_COOKIE['id_user']);
            $code_user=$db->screening($_COOKIE['code_user']);
            if ($db->query("SELECT * FROM `session` WHERE `id_user`=".$id_user.";", 'num_row', '')==1) {
                //~ Есть запись в таблице сессий, сверяем данные
                $data = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `session` WHERE `id_user`=".$id_user.";", 'accos', '');
                if ($data['code_sess']==$code_user and $data['user_agent_sess']==$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) {
                    //~ Данные верны, стартуем сессию
                    $_SESSION['id_user']=$id_user;
                    $_SESSION['login_user']=$db->query("SELECT login_user FROM `users` WHERE  `id_user` = '".$id_user."';", 'result', 0);
                    //~ обновляем куки
                    setcookie("id_user", $_SESSION['id_user'], time()+3600*24*14);
                    setcookie("code_user", $code_user, time()+3600*24*14);
                    return true;
                } else return false; //~ данные в таблице сессий не совпадают с куками
            } else return false; //~ в таблице сессий не найден такой пользователь
        } else return false;
    }
}
```

Строчки 100 и 101 в headers:

```
setcookie("id_user", $_SESSION['id_user'], time()+3600*24*14);
setcookie("code_user", $code_user, time()+3600*24*14);
```

Comment: зачем вам вообще эти данные в куках ? храните из в сессиях

Comment: нужны куки - так как удобно не вводить по тысячи раз логин и пароль. один раз ввел. браузер запомнил и все. автоматически все работает. а на сессиях - приходится постоянно подтверждать свой логин и пароль.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чудес не бывает.  У вас вызывается в коде функция check(), где проставляются куки, при этом уже куча HTML была выведена. Мало подключить все это дело до вывода чего-либо в браузер, все это нужно и использовать ДО вывода чего-либо в браузер.

```
<?php
include_once 'conf.php';

$auth = new auth(); //~ Создаем новый объект класса

//~ Авторизация
if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
    if (!$auth->authorization()) {
        $error = $_SESSION['error'];
        unset ($_SESSION['error']);
    }
}

//~ выход
if (isset($_GET['exit'])) $auth->exit_user();

$isAuth = $auth->check();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
...
            <li><?php if ($isAuth) $r.='Привет, '.$_SESSION['login_user'].'';
            else {
    $r.='Привет, Гость';}
print $r;?>!</li>...
```

Comment: вот до этого `//~ выход` сделайте проверку на авторизацию, т.е. до начала вывода страницы. результат запомните в переменную какую-нибудь, например `$isAuth` и уже ее проверяйте, а не вызывая функцию.

Comment: чтобы ничего не менять посмотрите в сторону Ob_Start()
Должно помочь...

Comment: можно и ob_* использовать. Дополнил ответ упрощенным кодом, по переносу результата в переменную.

Comment: Вроде все заработало) Спасибо!
Я авторизацию на куках проверяю на всех браузерах. Однако - почему-то в Safari и Firefox нет автоматического входа...Не подскажите. с чем это может быть связано?

Comment: К сожалению, не могу сейчас подсказать. Может там стоит запрет на сохранение кук, может какие-то другие настройки браузера.

Comment: А это может быть связано с тем, что для того, чтобы сработали куки - нужно хотя бы сессию отсидеть в браузере?